# Zsh: How to open Jira at current git branch without oh-my-zsh addon?

Tags: command-line, git, zsh, jira

If I'm using zsh and currently on a git branch `ABC-12312` which corresponds to a JIRA ticket and endpoint, how can I get to the endpoint from the CLI, without oh-my-zsh addon?

Answer (score 0):

After trial and error, this seems to be the minimalist script, using the built-in `vcs_info` command

I could be completely wrong, but I believe that it:

1. requires / enables `vcs_info`
2. styles future `vcs_info` return / replacement (try removing the second line and you will see the url change)
3. creates a function jira (where `$0` is the word `jira`, `$1` would be the next word, but we're using `$vcs_info_msg_0_`) that calls open with whichever default application handles the string format. `vcs_info` queries the git branch and registers the variable `vcs_info_msg_0_` for future usage

---

```
autoload -Uz vcs_info
zstyle ':vcs_info:git:*' formats '%b'

jira () {
  vcs_info
  open "http://jira.corp.asdf.com/browse/$vcs_info_msg_0_"
}
```